# FTP_DELETE not working?

Tags: php, oop, magento

Hey guys I have my script here that is supposed to *do some stuff* then delete a file, unfortunetly my files never unlink. I"m wondering what the reason for this might be? Permissions was the only thing I could think of, or maybe the output buffer is messing up? I really don't know, but would appreciate some advice on how to handle it. Issue in question is that last IF() block.

```
public function remoteFtp() {
    $enabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/use_ftp');
    $remove = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_remove_file');
    if ($enabled == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    $base_path = Mage::getBaseDir('base');


    $ftp_url = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_url');
    $ftp_user = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_user');
    $ftp_pass = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_password');
    $ftp_remote_dir = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_remote_dir');
    $ftp_filename_filter = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_remote_filename');

    $ftp_file = $base_path . '/edi/working/working.edi';

    $handle = fopen($ftp_file, 'w');
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_url);

    ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) or die("unable to login");

    if ($ftp_remote_dir) {
        ftp_chdir($conn_id, $ftp_remote_dir);
    }

    //is there a file
    $remote_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

    $exists = count($remote_list);

    if ($exists > 0) {
        $len = strlen($ftp_filename_filter) - 1;


        foreach ($remote_list as $name) {
            if (substr($ftp_filename_filter, 0, 1) == "*") {

                if (substr($name, '-' . $len) == substr($ftp_filename_filter, '-' . $len)) {
                    $ftp_remote_name = $name;
                }
            }
            if (substr($ftp_filename_filter, strlen($name) - 1) == "*") {
                if (substr($ftp_filename_filter, 0, $len) == substr($name, 0, $len)) {
                    $ftp_remote_name = $name;
                }
            }
            if ($ftp_filename_filter == $name) {
                $ftp_remote_name = $name;
            }
        }
    }


    if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $ftp_remote_name, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
        echo "successfully written to $ftp_file <br />";
        if ($remove == 1) {
            ftp_delete($conn_id, $ftp_remote_name);
        }
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while downloading $ftp_remote_name to $ftp_file <br />";
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

Comment: If you thought permissions might be the problem, did you check them?

Comment: Does it work when you try and do it manually with a GUI FTP client?

Comment: @ceejayoz I did check the permissions, as an ftp user they're at 0777,  it goes work on a GUI client, and I'm using the exact same credentials.

Comment: The next thing I would do would be sniff the network traffic with e.g. [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) and see what response you are getting back from FTP server. It will probably have a human-readable error message in it telling you what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that the system variable `$remove = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/settings/ftp_remove_file');` was set to BOOL(false)